# App data backup on android devices to google cloud

Tags: backup, google, restore, cloud

I have a question about the backup into google cloud on android devices. When you do a backup into google cloud also app data from apps which supports that feature will be uploaded too. But I think there are some conditions WHEN app data of a specific app will be uploaded. E. g. on my android device (Samsung Galaxy Note 9 on Android 8.1) there are some apps which won't upload app data and some apps which will upload data (even though they support it). It doesn't matter if the app data has changed, it won't upload to google cloud. So is there a way to start app data backup manually? Because app data backup has worked before. I can see this because of the "last updated" timestamp.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question and add the info which device (name) and what Android version you use because what is backuped by Google Cloud backup is Android version dependent.

Comment: I updated it, Samsung Galaxy Note 9 on Android 8.1

Comment: If the app specifies `allowBackup=false` in it's `AndroidManifest.xml` then cloud backup is disabled for this app.